# Adding the attribute Required to an input within Razor application with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

i have an asp.net mvc4 application , in which i have this form :

```
  <form method="Post" action="/User/Validate_Expert_Decision" target="_parent">
      <span>
          <b style="color:red" >Votre avis</b>
          <br />
          <br />

          <input type="radio" name="avis" value="1" checked>Validé &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
          <input type="radio" name="avis" value="2">Refusé &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
          <input type="radio" name="avis" value="3">Demande de spécification &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
          <input type="radio" name="avis" value="4">Demande d'analyse 
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />

      </span>
    <span>
        <b style="color:red" >
        Votre justification * 
        <b />

          <br />
          <br />
      <textarea rows="16" cols="75" name="justification"></textarea>
    </span>

    <input type="hidden" name="elem" value="0"  id="elem"/>
    <p> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
      <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Annuler" onClick="closebox()">
    </p>
  </form>
```

i need to add the attribute `required` to the textarea `justification` when the radio button takes 2, 3 or 4 as a value ie only for the first value the `justification` input isn't required.

So, how can i do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[name="avis"]').change(function () {
            var t = $('textarea[name="justification"]');

            if ($(this).val() != 1)
                t.attr('required', 'required');
            else
                t.removeAttr('required');
        })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything like this?

```
$("input[name='avis']").on("change", function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('td[name=justification]').prop("required", value != "1");
});
```